# SQL Server COALESCE() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a power automate flow that using to retrieve some data from the SQL server and I'm executing a SQL query. I need to return a value if it is null

Can anyone please tell me how to use a "COALESCE" function for this ?

Below is the script I'm using.

```
select *  from dbo.Employee
where DATEDIFF(dd,convert(date,startDate,103),CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))=90
```

Comment: Although I have answered the X of this [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), you should really explain what about the `COALESCE` function you don't understand; it is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Do you mean if startDate is NULL? And what should you return then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `COALESCE`, use an `OR` to check if the value of the column `IS NULL`. Also, don't get the number of days that have passed, use a date range and check if the value of `startDate` is between that range; then you will be a SARGable query.

If your columnm `startDate` is a date and time value, then you'd do this:

```sql
SELECT * --This should be an explicit list of columns, not *
FROM dbo.Employee E
WHERE (E.StartDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -90,GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE)
  AND  E.StartDate < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -89,GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE))
   OR E.StartDate IS NULL;
```

If it's just a `date` value, then this will work:

```sql
SELECT * --This should be an explicit list of columns, not *
FROM dbo.Employee E
WHERE E.StartDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -90,GETUTCDATE()) AS DATE)
   OR E.StartDate IS NULL;
```

This also **assumes** you don't have the fatal design flaw of storing a date and time value as a `varchar`, as your clause `convert(date,startDate,103)` *implies* you are. If you *are* storing your date (and time) values as a `varchar` (or other string based data type), then fixing your design is step 1; there are plenty of Q&As out there already explaining how to do this.